# How to create/handle complex join conditions in Analysis Services "Tabular" Model between two SCD Type2 tables with 1:M relationship?

Tags: ssas, reporting, dax, ssas-tabular, scd2

I am new to Analysis Services and working on a Tabular model design. Need experts advice/suggestion on the best approach and how to handle below scenarios.

Assuming, I have below two tables Department and Employee where I am storing data for different customers(tenants) and there’s one-to-many (1:M) relationship between these two tables (i.e. one department can have 1 or more employees)

However, let’s say both the tables are SCD Type 2 i.e. storing history with effective and termination dates. There are no constraints, indexes etc. created on these tables at database level.

```
Department table:
cust_id dept_id dept_name   efctv_dt    trmntn_dt   Dept_key
1001    D1      IT        12-01-2018    12-31-9999  1001D1
1001    D2      HR        01-01-2019    12-31-9999  1001D2
1002    D3      Admin     02-01-2019    02-28-2019  1002D3
1002    D3      HR+Admin  03-01-2019    12-31-9999  1002D3
1002    D4      Finance   02-01-2019    12-31-9999  1002D4

Employee table:
cust_id emp_id  emp_name    dept_id efctv_dt    trmntn_dt   Emp_key
1001    E1      XYZ          D1    01-01-2019   01-31-2019  1001D1
1001    E1      XYZ-A        D1    02-01-2019   12-31-9999  1001D1
1001    E2      ABC          D2    02-01-2019   12-31-9999  1001D2
1002    E3      AXBYCZ       D3    03-01-2019   03-31-2019  1002D3
1002    E3      AXBYCZ       D4    04-01-2019   12-31-9999  1002D4
1002    E4      DEFG         D4    04-01-2019   12-31-9999  1002D4
```

Columns cust_id & dept_id can be concatenated together as a separate column in both the tables as a key field and used as a join between both the tables.

Department Key=Concatenate(department[cust_id], department[dept_id] )

Employee Key=Concatenate(employee[cust_id], employee[dept_id] )

Example key output values= 1001D1, 1001D2, 1002D3, 1002D4

Now let’s say we have following reporting requirements, i.e.

To filter on Date Ranges (in visualization) - assuming there's another date dimension table with all dates & hierarchy

1) When no specific date range or filter selected - show all current active employee & departments names (where, trmntn_dt = 12-31-9999)
So, expected output is:

Emp Name    Dept Name
XYZ-A         IT
ABC           HR
AXBYCZ        Finance

2) When reporting for a specific month example - Jan-2019 - show all employees & department names active as of that month.
So, expected output is:

Emp Name    Dept Name
XYZ           IT

3) When reporting for a specific Quarter example - Q1-2019 - show all employees & department names active as of that quarter.
So, expected output is:

Emp Name    Dept Name
XYZ-A         IT
ABC           HR
AXBYCZ        HR+Admin

However, the join condition in AS Tabular model with 1:M relationship between these two tables would fail because the rows are not unique in the Department table (rows for D3), which is on the one side of the relationship.

If you include efctv_dt or trmntn_dt also in the concatenated join condition in both the tables as key for joining i.e.

Department Key=Concatenate(department[cust_id], department[dept_id] ) & Concatenate(department[efctv_dt],””))

Employee Key=Concatenate(employee[cust_id], employee[dept_id] ) & Concatenate(employee[efctv_dt],””))

Example key output values= 1001D112-01-2018, 1001D201-01-2019…

However, though now the rows would be unique since we don’t expect same row twice on the same day (unless some ETL issues like process ran twice on the same day etc.)

AS tabular model doesn’t allow to create complex join/condition (like in SAP BO Universe) so that we could add below condition when joining these two SCD type 2 tables as below which might help solve some of the requirements.

```
    dept.cust_id = emp.cust_id
And dept.dept_id = emp.dept_id
And ( calendar_date is between efctv_dt and trmntn_dt 
        Or 
       trmntn_dt = ’12-31-9999’
    )
```

I think for creating/calculating any measure value is still doable with lots of examples available online on DAX, but what about with just the dimensional attributes ?

Is this the right approach ? How to handle these?

Comment: Why does your Department table contain Customer ID? I think this table is incorrectly designed, and that's the source of your problems (you need to think carefully about the true grain of this table).

Comment: Hi RADO, that Customer ID is actually a Tenant ID and it should not to be confused with Employee ID . Assuming, the fact that you are building a SaaS application (for ex. HRMS system) which supports one of the multi-tenant data strategy i.e. using same database instance, schema and table for storing data for multiple/different clients/customers. For now, please forget about Customer ID field from these tables and let me know if this helps ?